# Fallo en la busqueda de cards en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, buscador

estoy creando un buscador en una pagina web que usa *react*, con el archivo **Searchcard.js** intento filtrar los datos usando una operación ternaria

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```

Esto lo que hace es que cuando **search** *(que es un estado para el input de buscar)* este vació me muestra todas las **cards** *(osea sin ningún filtro)*, pero si es que este **search** esta con algun valor **string** entonces busca o mejor dicho filtra los datos según el **valor en search**.
La primera operación se realiza bien, cuando no hay nada en search muestra todas las cards, **el problema es que cuando escribo algo en search por alguna razon que desconozco no me muestra ningún dato y el res en vez de que obtenga los datos como arreglo no muestra nada, solo un array vació *(esto lo veo gracias al console.log()).***

También intente con...

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```

Lo que muestra el archivo console.log cuando se ejecuta y se le asigna un valor para **search** en el **input**

El primer archivo **console.log** es para mostrar lo que captura la entrada de búsqueda, luego nos muestra un archivo **console.log(data)** que nos muestra los datos de la **API**, **console.log(res)** finalmente vemos una matriz que se supone debe almacenar los datos de las tarjetas elegidas por filtrado pero aparentemente esta **vació**

[image: console.log de los datos]

Agradecería si es que pudieran ayudarme a encontrar el error de este problema.
Dejare los codigos de *Searchcard.js*, el codigo de como *saque los datos* y como se *crean las cards*.

**Searchcard.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import {Cards} from '../cards/Cards'
import { UseFetch } from '../UseFetch'

export const Searchcard = () => {
    //hooks
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("https://aves.ninjas.cl/api/birds") 
    const estado = UseFetch(url) /*Devuelve el objeto que tiene UseFetch (cargando, data) */
    const {cargando, data} = estado /*obtener los datos del objeto que entrego UseFetch */
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
    
    //Funcion que nos ayuda a capturar los valores dados por el usuario
    const searcher = (e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value)
        console.log(e.target)
    }
    //Filtramos los datos
        const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    
  return (
    <div>
        <input value={search} onChange={searcher} type="text" placeholder='¡Busca un pajaro!' className='form-control'></input>
    
    {
          cargando 
          ?
          <h1>Cargando...</h1>
           :
           <div>
            <Cards data={res} />    
            {console.log(data)}  
            {console.log(res)}
          </div>
  }
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Searchcard
```

Los datos los saco desde una API publica.

Para lograr sacar los datos uso

**UseFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export const UseFetch = (url) => {
  const [resultado, setResultado] = useState({ cargando: true, dato: null })
  useEffect( ()=>{
    getData(url)
  },[url])
  async function getData(url) {
    try{
      setResultado({cargando: true, data:null})
      const respues = await fetch(url)       
      const data = await respues.json()       
      setResultado({ cargando: false, data })
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  return resultado
}
```

Para crear las cards uso cards.js y cardsbird.js

**cards.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Cardsbird} from './Cardsbird'
import './Cards.css'
import Paginacion from '../Pagination/Pagination'



export const Cards = ({data}) => {
  const [actPag, setactPag] = useState(1)
  const [cardXpag] = useState(20)

  

  //
  const indUltimo = actPag * cardXpag;
  const indPrimero = indUltimo - cardXpag;
  const actCard = data.slice(indPrimero, indUltimo); 
  
  //Cambiar pagina
  const paginate = numPag => setactPag(numPag);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      
        <ul className='cards'>
            {      actCard.map(p=>(
                  <li className='card-item' key={p.uid}>
                      <Cardsbird url={p._links.self}/>
                  </li>  
                ))
            }
            <div className='container2'><Paginacion cardXpag={cardXpag} totalCards={data.length} paginate={paginate}/></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

**cardsbird.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { UseFetch } from '../UseFetch'
import Modal from './Modal'


export const Cardsbird = ({url}) => {
    const estado = UseFetch(url)
    const {cargando, data} = estado 



  return (
    <div>
        {
            cargando
            ?
            <h1>Cargando...</h1> :
            <div className='card' style={{width:'14rem'}} data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={`#id${data.sort}`}>
                <div className='card-header'>
                    <h5 className='card-title'>{data.name.spanish}</h5>
                </div>
                <div className='card-body'>
                    <img src={data.images.main} alt={data.uid} />
                </div>
                <Modal id={`id${data.sort}`} titulo={data.name.spanish} imagen={data.images.main} audio={data.audio.file} descripcion={data.iucn.description} habitat={data.habitat} tamaño={data.size} mapa={data.map.image} />           
            </div>
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cardsbird
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error fue mi estupidez, porque no vi como se llama el **nombre de la card dentro de la API.**

Estaba llamando el nombre de esta manera

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```

Y debería ser así

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.name.spanish.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```